# Asterisk API - problem reaching from browser

Tags: api, asterisk

I have configured Issabel with Asterisk :

```
[root@issabel ~]# asterisk -V
Asterisk 11.25.3
```

enabled mini http server at /etc/asterisk/http.conf
enabled manager access at /etc/asterisk/manager.conf

http.conf:

```
#include http_additional.conf
#include http_custom.conf
[general]
enabled=yes
enablestatic=yes
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=8080
prefix=
tlsenable=no
tlsbindaddr=
tlscertfile=
tlsprivatekey=
```

manager.conf:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
port = 5038
#include manager_general_additional.conf

[admin]
username = foo
secret = bar
#deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0
read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate
write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate
writetimeout = 5000
httptimeout = 36000

#include manager_additional.conf
#include manager_custom.conf
```

i am trying to create some API based on this article:
[https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Allow+Manager+Access+via+HTTP][1]

the article says , that first i must log in via:
http://localhost:8088/manager?action=login&username=foo&secret=bar

of course i have issabel server in my local network, so i am trying to log in from Chrome:
http://**192.168.0.100**:8088/manager?action=login&username=foo&secret=bar

the result is the following:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Asterisk Server
```

the ports on the server are open, listening, no firewall blocking them - i can telnet these ports 8080 and 5038 from my command line

netstat on my issabel server:

```
[root@issabel ~]# netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1181/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20004         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2558/php            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2011/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1181/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5038            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2526/asterisk       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4559            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2587/hfaxd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2526/asterisk       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      981/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1658/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      979/httpd           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1181/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1181/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      2414/cyrus-master   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      979/httpd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      981/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1658/master
```

My goal is, to show the calling numbers to my CallCenter operators , find these numbers in my local database and display the caller names with the data needed to handle the cutomers in our information system based on web.

```
[root@issabel static-http]# ls -la ./
total 696
drwxrwxr-x   2 asterisk asterisk   4096 Jul 15  2019 .
drwxrwxr-x. 14 asterisk asterisk   4096 Jun  8 06:12 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk   6066 Jun  6  2018 ajamdemo.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk    461 Jun  6  2018 astman.css
-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk   7912 Jun  6  2018 astman.js
-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk 573949 Jun  6  2018 core-en_US.xml
-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk   4170 Jun  6  2018 mantest.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 asterisk asterisk  96653 Jun  6  2018 prototype.js
```

any hint appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You also need install web files in correct location.

Check that you have files in /var/lib/asterisk/static-http/

Comment: please check my updated question with dir listing for that directory

Answer (score 0):

cp -Rfv /var/lib/asterisk/* /usr/share/asterisk/

Comment: this one valid only for older debian and ubuntu and not valid for any current distro at all.